# Need to create a program that in PYTHON that takes the average of test scores and determines a letter grade on them

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, syntax, python-3.4

Let me start off by saying I know a similar question has been asked before, I have browsed them but none of them were helpful to me. I have to create this program in python using functions. Functions still confuse me a bit. I have come up with this below. I do not understand where I am going wrong. Any help would be extremely useful. Thank you to anyone out there.

```
def main():
    score1 = int(input('Enter grade 1: ')
    score2 = int(input('Enter grade 2: ')
    score3 = int(input('Enter grade 3: ')
    score4 = int(input('Enter grade 4: ')
    score5 = int(input('Enter grade 5: ')

    average = calc_average(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5)
    print('Your average score is ', average)               

    determine_grade(average)

def calc_average(score1,score2,score3,score4,score5):
    avscore = (score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5)/5
    return avscore

def determine_grade():
    if avscore < 60:
        print('Average score:', avscore , 'F')
    elif score >=60 and <=69:
        print('Average score:', avscore , 'D')
    elif score >=70 and <=79:
        print('Average score:', avscore , 'C')
    elif score >=80 and <=89:
        print('Average score:', avscore , 'B')
    elif score >=90 and <=100:
        print('Average score:', avscore , 'A')
    else:
        print('Error: This is not a number inbetween 0 and 100.')
    return avscore

main()
```

Comment: what error/unexpected result are you seeing that makes you think you are doing this incorrectly?

Comment: Is the code posted as it appears in your script? Indentation is important in python, and the code posted is not indented correctly.

Comment: avscore is not a global variable - you need do `def determine_grade(avscore)`

Comment: I edited it to fix the indentation from when it was originally posted - I assumed it was just pasted in wrong but yeah it could be wrong in the actual code

Comment: What is `av=score`?

Comment: @Andrew On SO we generally _don't_ fix indentation errors in other people's Python questions since wrong indentation may be the thing that's causing their problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well at the top your score1, score2,... inputs are missing a ")" at the end. However there are a few different things broken in the code. The main thing that is stopping this from working besides the syntax and variable naming is the line `determine_grade(average)` where you try to pass that function your average score but you don't have any arguments on that function when you define it.

Add an argument to that and fix the elif statements (`and <=69` doesn't work because you need to restate what you are comparing to, ie. `and score <=69` or something)

Also watch what you call your variables as it can get confusing when passing them back and forth between functions. In your determine_grade function you are using "avscore" and "score" interchangeably.

If you fix those things the code runs fine.